# Javascript format date /Date(-62135571600000)/

Tags: javascript, formatdatetime

How do I format the following to a 'mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss' date in javascript?

```
/Date(-62135571600000)/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my current time zone:

```
new Date(-62135571600000); //=> Mon Jan 01 1 02:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Is that what you're looking for?  So you can easily pull out the date properties you want from that object to format it as you like...

Answer (score 1):

```
// create a new date object from the timestamp...
var p = (new Date(-62135571600000)).toISOString().split(/\D+/)
// format the date
var formatted = [p[1],p[2],p[0]].join("/")+" "+[p[3],p[4],p[5]].join(":")
// check it...
alert(formatted)
```

`(new Date(-62135571600000))` returns a date object, which when output as a string looks like... `Mon Jan 01 1 07:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)`. Internally, javascript understands it as a date. Next, we convert it `.toISOString()`, so the format looks more like... `0001-01-01T07:00:00.000Z` - which is ISO standard date format. Next, we split it into an array by any non-digit characters using regex (`.split(/\D+/)`), which gives us something like... `["0001", "01", "01", "07", "00", "00", "000", ""]`. Finally, we assign that to a variable... `var p = ...`.

Now we have the date parts in the `p` array, we can assemble them as we wish. Firstly, joining the parts 1, 2 and 0 (0 is year, 1 is month, 2 is day) with slashes (`[p[1],p[2],p[0]].join("/")`) giving `0001-01-01`. Next we add a space `...+" "+...` and join the times together... `[p[3],p[4],p[5]].join(":")`. Assign the result to a variable... `var formatted = ...` and we are good to go!